# Send Sol alongside a program method

Tags: anchor, solana-program

So i just simply want to send SOL and executing a program method in the same transaction.

I want the sol to go to the newly created keypair.

The program method works fine, but i can't get the transfer part working,
I'm getting this error: Error: Signature verification failed.

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js';
const endpoint = "https://explorer-api.devnet.solana.com";
const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection(endpoint); 

// let connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet')); tried both connection methods
const post = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

let tx = new web3.Transaction().add(
    web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
        toPubkey: post.publicKey,
        lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL //Investing 1 SOL. Remember 1 Lamport = 10^-9 SOL.
    }),
);

tx.add(await program.methods
    .sendPost(block, content, username)
    .accounts({
        author: wallet.publicKey.toBase58(),
        post: post.publicKey.toBase58(),
    })
    .signers([post])
    .instruction())

const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
tx.feePayer = await wallet.publicKey;
tx.recentBlockhash = await latestBlockHash.blockhash;


try {
    let signed = await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
    // The signature is generated
    let signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize());
    // Confirm whether the transaction went through or not
    await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: signature,
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Which wallet are you using when you get this signature verification error?

Comment: Phantom browser wallet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to sign the transaction with the wallet as well. Since you're trying to debit the `wallet` keypair, you'll want to include them as a signer on the transaction.

Then you can just set up the transaction like this:

```
const transferIx = web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
    toPubkey: post.publicKey,
    lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
});
const sendPostIx = await program.methods
    .sendPost(block, content, username)
    .accounts({
        author: wallet.publicKey,
        post: post.publicKey,
    })
    .instruction();
const tx = new web3.Transaction().add(transferIx).add(sendPostIx);
await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    tx,
    [wallet, post]
);
```

If you're using the Wallet Adapter in React, you should be able to just use the `sendTransaction` method from the `useWallet()` hook like this:

```
const transferIx = web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
    toPubkey: post.publicKey,
    lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
});
const sendPostIx = await program.methods
    .sendPost(block, content, username)
    .accounts({
        author: wallet.publicKey,
        post: post.publicKey,
    })
    .signers([post])
    .instruction();
const tx = new web3.Transaction().add(transferIx).add(sendPostIx);
const sx = await sendTransaction(tx, connection); // From useWallet()
await connection.confirmTransaction(sx);
```

Comment: i tried both of your methods, same problem, Signature verification failed

Comment: Could you share some more of your code?